# How to handle moving of a file while open in python

Tags: python, file, unix, move, fopen

In the below case, I wanted to read a file and have got the handle. But the file is moved to some other location and new data is being written.

```
In [2]: !echo "1\n2\n3" > /var/tmp/file
In [3]: !cat /var/tmp/file
1\n2\n3
In [4]: fh =open("/var/tmp/file", 'r')
In [8]: fh.readlines()
Out[8]: ['1\\n2\\n3\n']
In [9]: !mv /var/tmp/file /var/tmp/file.test
In [10]: !echo "new text" >| /var/tmp/file
In [11]: fh.readlines()
Out[11]: []
```

Here, I will have to read both "1\n2\n3\n" and "new text". How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code, neither of which has to do with the fact that the file moved. Moving a file has no effect on the open file object `fh`.

The first issue is that your shell redirection is overwriting the existing data in the file, not appending to it. `>` will redirect output to a file, but fail if the file exists and the shell option `noclobber` has been set. However, `>|` will always overwrite a file, regardless of the `noclobber` option. So you are *removing* the existing data and *replacing* it with the string `"new text"`.

So why doesn't the call to `fh.readlines()` work? It's about the the current read position. The first string has length 10 when written to the file. So after the first call to `readlines()`, `fh.tell() == 10`. Then you overwrite the file's contents with `new text\n`, which has length 9. So the second call to `fh.readlines()` returns nothing as the read position is beyond the end of the file.

If you do `fh.seek(0)` and then `fh.readlines()`, you'll get the expected text. If you don't overwrite, but *append* to the file with `!echo "new text" >> /var/tmp/file`, you'll get the expected data without any seeking.

Comment: No. Its not happening

Comment: `In [1]: !echo "1\n2\n3" > /var/tmp/file`
`In [2]: !cat /var/tmp/file`
`1\n2\n3`
`In [3]: fh =open("/var/tmp/file", 'r')`
`In [4]: fh.readlines()`
`Out[4]: ['1\\n2\\n3\n']`
`In [5]: !mv /var/tmp/file /var/tmp/file.test`
`In [6]: !echo "new text" > /var/tmp/file`
`In [7]: fh.readlines()`
`Out[7]: []`
`In [8]: fh.seek()`
`In [9]: fh.seek(0)`
`In [10]: fh.readlines()`
`Out[10]: ['1\\n2\\n3\n']`